# Forward a meeting request as a plain email message in Outlook 2010

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, forwarding, meeting-request

Microsoft has documentation about turning an e-mail message into a meeting request, at least for Outlook 2003:

**Turn a message into a meeting request - Outlook - Office.com**
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-a-message-into-a-meeting-request-HP003064164.aspx

But now I would like to do something that is, in a sense, the opposite: I want to forward a meeting request to another person, but as a simple/plain email message (NOT as a meeting request), in Microsoft Outlook 2010. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was bugging me too and I didnt want to set the contact properties. So I dug some more and found an even easier method (its still not as easy as it should be).

1. Start a new e-mail message
2. Select Insert -> Outlook item
3. Select "Insert as text" over on the right-hand side of the window
4. Select either the Inbox calender invite or select calender and then the item itself.

Voila.

Comment: I believe this is a better solution. I dont want to have to to change the properties of all the contacts that i want to do this to.

Answer (score 9):

I do this in Outlook 2007, I would imagine its the same in 2010.

1. Select the meeting invite
2. Click "Reply" or hit CTRL+R
3. Change the recipient to whoever you like and send.

Comment: Accepted answer might be the 'proper' way to do it, but this one is the most practical. I also find that this puts the contents in a more readable format than when inserting as outlook item.

Comment: Amazing, it does not work with "Forward", but it works with "Reply". Outlook 2016 is evil!

Answer (score 3):

Right-mouse click on the calendar item in the calendar view and choose "Reply" from the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done by changing the properties of the contact person to only send them plain text. I tested it and it works.

1. Open that specific contact by double clicking the item in your
   Contacts folder
2. Hover on the email address of the contact and a Address Card pop-up
   will become visible.
3. On the right side of the contact card you’ll see a menu button.
   Click on it and from the list choose; Outlook Properties
4. Make sure that the “Internet format” is set to “Let Outlook decide
   the best sending format”.

Source: [E-mail properties for contact addresses in Outlook 2010](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/449)

Answer (score 1):

Using reply loses any attachments.
"Insert an outlook item" sends the calendar entry as an attachment so the recipient can't immediately read the message, or inserts just the text so you lose attachments and formatting.
Some other things require messing with contacts (why? so absurd).

If the appointment is more than basic text then I have found nothing better than plain old copy/paste.  Select the appointment message and press Forward.  Select/copy the entire contents.  Create "New E-mail" and paste into it.
$0.10

Answer (score 1):

Same question for me for a long time too but recently I discovered a very simple solution to this question. By the way I am using outlook for office 365 (not sure however if this feature available too in other versions) I just feel it is worth sharing although the question was a long time ago this might still help others.
This is how it goes:

1. Open the meeting invite from the Calendar
2. Click 'File' (upper left). You would then see 'Info'
3. Under 'Info' you would see two tabs to the right - 'Move to Folder' and 'Properties'
4. Click 'Move to Folder' and there appears 'Copy to Folder'
5. Click 'Copy to Folder' and window will pop up with the folder list.
6. Select 'Archive' from the list then click 'Ok' then there you go - draft email right away bearing all the meeting information .